# Sqlite unrecognized token while inserting values

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'HRH™": , while compiling: INSERT INTO `w` VALUES (310346,-42,13,3,5399,'mightyhakizimi',2978,'mightyhakizimi',130,'HRH™
```

I am inserting values to my database from sqlite dump file, which could have bad characters like in this exception, how to check for all possible bad characters in every insert query for this? My insert code is there.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath),"utf-8");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

db.beginTransaction();


while (br.ready()) {
    String insertStmt = br.readLine();

    db.execSQL(insertStmt);

}
br.close();
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Comment: Where do these bad characters come from? Did the dump file get corrupted?

Comment: I think i misunderstood this exception, that file is downloaded from internet and somehow sometimes download stops in middle of transfer. So, mysql query do not have end in that way, so because of wrong syntax i get this error. i think... maybe after that exception i will do one more try to download that file.